# Count all roles in a discord server : discord.js v12

Tags: discord, discord.js

as the title states, I'm trying to count all the roles in a discord server. However, all the methods I found were members within a role. I've tried using these methods but none of them seemed to work:

```
var totalRoles = message.guild.roles.size;
```

and

```
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("ID HERE");
var totalRoles = guild.roles.size;
```

However, I keep getting `undefined` as the results returned. So, is there any way I can properly count the amount of roles in a discord server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was pretty quick but I've found the answer for anyone interested in the future:

`var totalRoles = message.guild.roles.cache.size;`